# What are the recommended best practices for and common pitfalls of using Compile?

Tags: compile, documentation, ccompilerdriver

As evidenced in [my last question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194059/why-wont-nominally-compilable-function-compile-err-compilecpintlt) there is much I do not know about how to write compilable functions.

The basics are clear: one must load the appropriate packages

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver``"]
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
```

and should check the availability of a suitable compiler:

```
CCompilers[Full]
```

and it is helpful to remind oneself of the functions that can be used that avoid `MainEvaluate` (for which I had not recorded the source but am now happy to credit to [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions) where there is also other useful information)

```
Compile`CompilerFunctions[] // Sort
Internal`CompileValues[];(*to trigger \
auto-load*)ClearAttributes[Internal`CompileValues, ReadProtected];
syms = DownValues[Internal`CompileValues] /. 
   HoldPattern[
     Verbatim[HoldPattern][Internal`CompileValues[sym_]] :> _] :> sym;
Complement[syms, Compile`CompilerFunctions[]]
```

But, once all that is done must still remember that a compiled function definition expects its arguments to be of well-defined kinds - Integer, Real, Complex and n-dimensional tensors (matrices).

What is unclear, even after re-reading documentation, is the proper specification and use of temporary variables. It appears, for example, that these too must be of simple types and that the compiler does not automatically coerce them to compatible types. Then too there is the question of using e.g. GetElement even thought Part is a compilable function, and why Do may be better than Table.

Where can such additional information be found and what guidance would the community offer re writing functions for compilation?

Comment: I presume you are aware of this [older thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096) as well?

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive I was but did not remember the details; thanks for the prompt. I have acknowledged that input.

Comment: "It appears, for example, that these too must be of simple types [...]". Of course. How else should it be possible to generate native C code? `GetElement` is faster than `Part` but also more fragile: If not used carefulle, it may cause a kernel crash (because, e.g., the operating system detects that _Mathematica_ tries to access memory that it is not to allowed to have access to.). `Table` has to allocate memory for the output while `Do` does not. So `Do` is faster if no output is to be generated.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Since we are not writing C code but Mathematica code the neophyte (me) does not necessarily *know* or think about how smart the cross-compiler is, so the simple types observation might benefit others as ignorant as I. The observations re GetElement & Tables are useful, thanks.

Comment: There is a [guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compile/tutorial/Overview.html) to the compiler that discusses available types, among other things

Comment: @MichaelE2 The compiler guide is very useful, thank you.